# How to send POST data using JSON in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I tried to add an entry to db using a POST request in Objectve-C. My service is:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "content-type=application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
boolean addEmployee(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    try {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, user.getCountry());
        userDataService.addUser(user);

        return true;
        //return new Status(1, "Employee added Successfully !");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;//new Status(0, e.toString());
    }

}
```

When I try this on Postman, it's working fine with `x-www-form-urlencoded`. But when I try this in Objective-C, nothing happens. Here is what I tried:

```
NSString *jsonInputString = @"{\"userName\":\"abcd\"}";

NSString *jsonRequest = jsonInputString;

NSLog(@"jsonRequest is %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/user"];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSMutableURLRequest *rq = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *jsonData = [jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[rq setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[rq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[rq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[jsonData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:rq queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}];
```

In completion block, the log prints "Could not connect to the server". How can I call the service with JSON data?

Comment: Given that the this client code looks to be in good shape, most of the things that can go wrong are on the connection-server side.  Can you get this working in CURL and post that CURL here?  (consider using [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] as the queue parameter).

Comment: I would take the log message as meaning that no one is listening on localhost:8080 ... It's way before the json is sent or even processed server-side.

Comment: Oh. I figure out the problem. I run this using iPhone. in that case localhost means iPhone's localhost. Any way to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Something like this should work

// 1: Create your URL, Session config and Session

NSString *jsonInputString = @"{\"userName\":\"abcd\"}";

NSString *jsonRequest = jsonInputString;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/user"];

  NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
      [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

  // 2: Create NSMutableRequest object
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
  request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

  // 3: Create Jsondata object
  NSError *error = nil;
 NSData *jsonData = [jsonInputString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

  // Asynchronously Api is hit here
  NSURLSessionUploadTask *dataTask =
      [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                            fromData:data
                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,
                                       NSError *error) {

                       NSLog(@"%@", data);

                       NSDictionary *json =
                           [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                           options:0
                                                             error:nil];
                       NSLog(@"%@", json);
                       success(json);
                   }];

  [dataTask resume]; // Executed First
```